# How to get different clusters using OPTICS in python by varying the parameter xi?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, optics-algorithm

I am trying to fit OPTICS clustering model to my data using python's `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.cluster import OPTICS, cluster_optics_dbscan
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data.loc[:, features])

op = OPTICS(max_eps=20, min_samples=10, xi=0.1)
op = op.fit(x)
```

From this fitted model, I get the reachability distances (`op.reachability_`) and the ordering (`op.ordering_`) of the points and also the cluster labels (`op.labels_`)

Now, I want to check how the clusters would vary by changing the parameter `xi` (0.01 in this case). Can I do this without fitting the model again and again with different `xi`'s (which takes a lot of time)?

Or, in other words, is there a `scikit-learn` function that takes the reachability distances (`op.reachability_`), the ordering (`op.ordering_`) of the points and `xi` as input and outputs the cluster labels?

I found a function `cluster_optics_dbscan` which "[performs DBSCAN extraction for an arbitrary epsilon given reachability-distances, core-distances and ordering and epsilon](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.cluster_optics_dbscan.html#sklearn.cluster.cluster_optics_dbscan)" (***Not quite what I want***)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A priori, you need to call the fit method, which is doing the actual cluster computation, as stated in the [function description](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.OPTICS.html).

However, if you look at the [optics](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/cluster/_optics.py) class, the `cluster_optics_xi`  function *"automatically extract clusters according to the Xi-steep method"*, calling both the `_xi_cluster` and `_extract_xi_labels` functions, which both take the `xi` parameter as input. So, by using them and refactoring a bit, you may be able to achieve what you want.